# How to convert Array to string in PHP without using implode method?

Tags: php, arrays

I Have an Array like this,
`$arr = array_diff($cart_value_arr,$cart_remove_arr);` 
I Want  to convert it to string without using implode method anyother way is there? And Also i want to remove $cart_remove_arr from $cart_value_arr the array_diff method i used it is correct?

Comment: `var_export` maybe? Not really sure what result you are looking for though...

Comment: There's probably a million ways to convert an array to a string. What is your goal?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `json_encode`

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

This will also work on multi dimensional arrays

Will result to:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

Another way is the classic `foreach` plus `string concatenation`

```
$string = '';
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $string .= $value . ', ';
}
echo rtrim($string, ', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way is to use `serialize()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), as simple as...

```
$string = serialize($arr);
```

This can handle most types and `unserialize()` to rebuild the original value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart_remove_arr = array(0 => 1, 1=> 2, 2 => 3);
$cart_value_arr = array(0 => 5, 1=> 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4, 4 => 6);
$arr = array_diff($cart_value_arr, $cart_remove_arr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);

$string = "";

foreach($arr as $value) {
    $string .= $value.', ';
}
echo $string;

**Output: Naveen want to remove $cart_remove_arr from $cart_value_arr
Remaining array**
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 6
)
he want a similar out as implode()
**String** 5, 4, 6,
```